# How to add voice to a video using microphone in wp8

Tags: windows-phone

I want to dub a video in my windows phone application. I want to know that how can i  modify any video and add our voice to that video.i am able to play video by using MediaElement

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to edit the actual video, but you might be able to trigger the audio to play at the appropriate time. This way there isn't actual editing of the video, but you might be able to get the audio to play over the video the way you were looking for. The link below explains the concept of media markers to trigger events based on media playback time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189078%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#anchor_mediaelement_mediamarkers